# OrangePi Lite2 OpenCL Driver

Tags: opencl, mali, orange-pi

I have recently purchased OrangePi's Lite2 development board, with Allwinner H6 SOC, which includes Quad-Core A53 + T720 Mali GPU.

In the H6 SPEC, it clearly states that the GPU supports OpenCL 1.1 API, however, the Ubuntu (Desktop vesrion) image I've installed from OrangePi's site doesn't include the OpenCL driver and I cannot find it anywhere on the web.

Is it possible that although the GPU itself supports OpenCL (in terms of hardware) Allwinner never implemented the driver for it? Or am I supposed to somehow recompile the Linux kernel with the Mali drivers?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Arm Community](https://community.arm.com/graphics/f/discussions/5659/who-can-supply-libmali-so-under-x11-used-with-dx910-sw-99002-r4p0-00rel0):

> In this instance the SoC (System on chip) for the OrangePi2 is by Allwinner. You will need to contact Allwinner and ask them if they are willing to provide Shenzhen Xunlong Software the binaries you need for the OrangePi2.

The respone I got from AllWinner was:

> Sorry，we do not open the OpenCL driver platform.

Which I translated as "Good luck in your future endeavors"